# How to delete all my photos in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Any advise on how I can delete all my photos in Google Photos?

I accidentally synced all the pictures from my iPhone, and now they consume all my 15gb capacity.

I highly appreciate any advise or workaround for this.

Comment: A less-hassle option is to go to settings in google photos, and change the 'upload size' to high quality, rather than 'original'.  High quality photos do not count towards your quota.   Any existing photos get compressed from original size down to high quality, but at least none of the photos now count toward your shared quota across mail, drive and photos

Comment: I wrote a tool to automatically select items in google photos. maybe it might help someone... http://ddorda.net/archives/1872

Comment: There's a chrome extension that deletes all Google Photos now: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bebhhjmapjadpdkkhbkpnpbjhkhndofl

Answer (score 10):

After a quick research I found two solutions:

The easy one is, and will work in any amount of images:

> delete from Google Photos folder on your Google
>   drive

[reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/0_qlEiZ0oE0)

the second one is, but a lot of users says that it will not work for the large amount of data:

1. In a browser go to photos.google.com
2. Select Photos from the left side menu
3. Hover over your first photo and then click the checkmark that
   appears to select it
4. Grab the scroll bar on the right and go all the way down to your
   last photo
5. Holding down the Shift key select the last photo in the
       bottom right
6. Click the Trashcan icon

[reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95834/delete-all-content-from-google-photos)

Comment: Adding an alternative here: https://github.com/mrishab/google-photos-delete-tool

Comment: @pcambra Your tool works great.

Comment: The first "easy way" doesn't work, and the second is very painful, if (like me) you have thousands of photos going back years. (I need to remove that because I migrate to a different Google account.)

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128858?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0):

> **Remove photos and videos**
>
> 1. On your computer, go to photos.google.com
> 2. Place your cursor over items you want to move to trash. At the top left, click Select check mark
> 3. At the top right, click Trash
> 4. **To permanently delete photos and videos**, click Menu > **Trash** > select the photo or video > Trash

If Google Photos synchronized with Google Drive, then go to **Google Drive**, and under the default option “**My Drive**” find the folder “**Google Photos**”. Inside you should have folders for each year. Delete them all and you have no pictures on your account.

Comment: I don't really want to do this 6,000 times, and the photos view has now been removed from google drive.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to delete all, making 10000 click is NOT a solution